# ClassPath in manifest does not work

Tags: java, classpath, manifest.mf

Structure of files in my jar is:

```
com/my/Main.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
RXTXcomm.jar
```

Manifest.mf consist:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.my.Main
Class-Path: RXTXcomm.jar
```

(empty line present)

When I run my jar as: `java -jar my.jar`

I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is wrong?

You have packaged the jar dependency inside your main jar. The intention of `Class-Path` is to add an external jar to the classpath, with the path relative to the location of the main jar.

Packaging a jar within a jar is not supported by standard Java classloaders. If you want, you can explode the inner jar into the main jar, though. Maven can do this for you.

Comment: Then how to give relative path of the dependent jar that need to be packaged with the new jar?

Comment: Simple answer is you cannot. Workaround may be to package them as Zip with the dependant jar in a subfolder. Then you can add Class-Path: subfolder/RXTXcomm.jar in the manifest of main jar.

Answer (score 2):

The RXTXcomm.jar must not be inside the jar file, but outside of it. Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).